# Having trouble updating state in React after API call

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a textbox with an autocomplete feature that pulls suggestions from an API but having trouble updating the state after I receive the array from the API.  I am modifying code from here: https://blog.bitsrc.io/building-a-react-autocomplete-component-from-scratch-b78105324f4c

I think I have to use ComponentDidMount() but I am not sure how to apply it to an onChange Function.

```js
      class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return (
            <div className="App">
                <Autocomplete/>
           </div>
         );
        }
      }

      class Autocomplete extends React.Component{
        state = {
          activeOption: 0,
          filteredOptions: [],
          showOptions: false,
          userInput: ''
        };

        onChange = (e) => {
          const userInput = e.currentTarget.value;

          fetch("/places", {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(userInput)
            }).
            then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => data.filter(element =>
              element.PlaceName.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1))
            .then(filteredOptions => this.setState(
            {
            activeOption: 0,
            filteredOptions: filteredOptions,
            showOptions: true,
            userInput: e.currentTarget.value
          }));
        };
.
.
.
.
  render() {
       const {
         onChange,
         onClick,
         onKeyDown,

         state: { activeOption, filteredOptions, showOptions, userInput }
       } = this;
       let optionList;
       if (showOptions && userInput) {
         console.log(filteredOptions)
         if (filteredOptions.length) {
           optionList = (
             <ul className="options">
               {filteredOptions.map((optionName, index) => {
                 let className;
                 if (index === activeOption) {
                   className = 'option-active';
                 }
                 return (
                   <li className={className} key={optionName} onClick={onClick}>
                     {optionName}
                   </li>
                 );
               })}
             </ul>
           );
         } else {
           optionList = (
             <div className="no-options">
               <em>No Option!</em>
             </div>
           );
         }
       }
       return (
         <React.Fragment>
           <div className="search">
             <input
               type="text"
               className="search-box"
               onChange={onChange}
               onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
               value={userInput}
             />
             <input type="submit" value="" className="search-btn" />
           </div>
           {optionList}
         </React.Fragment>
       );
     }
   }
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Once I try and run this, I get two errors: one for a synthetic event being reused for performance issues and one for a component changing an controlled input

Comment: `fetch` returns a promise, so by the time the promise resolves the synthetic react event has likely already been nullified and returned to the event pool; call `persist` on the event to keep it around, or destructure/save the value *before* calling `fetch`. The second error is likely related to the `value` changing from an undefined to defined value, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a setTimeout in the onChange method. And if the user doesn't type, you make the request, in other wise, you can't make the request

Comment: I think you are referring to the process of debouncing, which doesn't answer the question but would be a great addition to this code.  Would recommend using a library for this instead of rolling your own, like Lodash for example:  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were anticipating the `filteredOptions` variable to be a list of strings.  It is actually a list of objects, which was causing React to throw the "object not allowed as children" error.  Also, you can't use the event object to set state as it is already released.  However, you were already storing the value in a variable which you could use, `userInput`.  I updated your code with some very minor tweaks, and it appears to work.  Take a look at a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-elgamal-gxjo3?file=/src/App.js):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Autocomplete />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Autocomplete extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeOption: 0,
    filteredOptions: [],
    showOptions: false,
    userInput: ""
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    const userInput = e.currentTarget.value;

    // Mock out the API call and JSON
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => {
        const data = [
          { PlaceName: "Place 1" },
          { PlaceName: "Place 2" },
          { PlaceName: "Another Place 1" },
          { PlaceName: "Another Place 2" }
        ];
        return data.filter(
          (element) =>
            element.PlaceName.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) >
            -1
        );
      })
      .then((filteredOptions) =>
        this.setState({
          activeOption: 0,
          filteredOptions: filteredOptions,
          showOptions: true,
          userInput: userInput
        })
      );
  };

  render() {
    const {
      onChange,
      onClick,
      onKeyDown,

      state: { activeOption, filteredOptions, showOptions, userInput }
    } = this;
    let optionList;
    if (showOptions && userInput) {
      if (filteredOptions.length) {
        optionList = (
          <ul className="options">
            {filteredOptions.map((option, index) => {
              let className;
              if (index === activeOption) {
                className = "option-active";
              }
              return (
                <li
                  className={className}
                  key={option.PlaceName}
                  onClick={onClick}
                >
                  {option.PlaceName}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        );
      } else {
        optionList = (
          <div className="no-options">
            <em>No Option!</em>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="search">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="search-box"
            onChange={onChange}
            onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
            value={userInput}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="" className="search-btn" />
        </div>
        {optionList}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```